# Не получается поставить JavaScript событие на кнопку

Tags: javascript, битрикс

Поставил цель на сайт(JavaScript событие) на кнопку добавить в корзину , цель не работает. CMS битрикс. вот собственно код кнопки bitrix:catalog.element.php код:

```
<div class="catalog-element-buy_buttons"><?    
?><noindex><form class="js-buyform js-buyform<? 

=$BUY_ID?>" name="buy_form" yaCounter28360211.reachGoal('push_button');return 
true;><?
```

Все ли я верно сделал или что то с синтексацией ? Если кто сталкивался прошу помочь. Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так

`onsubmit="yaCounter28360211.reachGoal('push_button');return 
true;"`

Хотя исходя из вашего вопроса событие вешать надо на кнопку, а не на форму. Тогда найдите кнопку и пропишите так:

`onclick="yaCounter28360211.reachGoal('push_button');return 
true;"`